# 405 Method Not Allowed - (1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Hi i have this delete button which i really want to pass using ajax call. My problem is that when the delete button is clicked this is the error that i get 
`NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed` and  `(1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. This is my code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.delete-block').on("click","a#deleteBtn", function() {
            var x = confirm("Do you want to delete this?");
            if(x){
                var id = $(this).data("deleteid");
                $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url: $(this).data("href"),
                    data: {
                        id: id
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#deleteId"+ id).fadeOut('slow'); 
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<tbody>
    @foreach($datas as $post)
    <tr class="delete-block" id="deleteId{{ $post['id'] }}">
        <td>{{ $post['title']}}</td>
        <td>{{ $post['post'] }} </td>
        <td>{{ $post['comments'] }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ url('home/edit', $post['id']) }}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" id="deleteBtn" data-deleteid="{{ $post['id'] }}" data-href="{{ action('AddRecordController@destroy', $post['id']) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Im using the `action('AddRecordController@destroy', $post['id'])` since my AddRecordController is being generated. And my route is only this one

```
Route::resource('addRecord', 'AddRecordController');
```

My AddRecordController code below

```
public function destroy($id){
        //
        echo "Test";
        echo $id;
        $addRecord = Addrecord::find($id);
        $addRecord->delete();
    }
```

Can someone help me figured this thing out? Any help is muchly appreciated.
TIA.

Comment: You need to use the ``DELETE`` method. You can use [form method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing) to do this.

Comment: You mean the form method when deleting the data? no using on a javascropt/ajax call?

Comment: You can use AJAX. You just need to add ``"_method": "DELETE", `` to the data.

Comment: You mean this one? <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `DELETE` method. You can use [form method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing) to do this.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.delete-block').on("click","a#deleteBtn", function() {
            var x = confirm("Do you want to delete this?");
            if(x){
                var id = $(this).data("deleteid");
                $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url: $(this).data("href"),
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        "_method": "delete"
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#deleteId"+ id).fadeOut('slow'); 
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<tbody>
    @foreach($datas as $post)
    <tr class="delete-block" id="deleteId{{ $post['id'] }}">
        <td>{{ $post['title']}}</td>
        <td>{{ $post['post'] }} </td>
        <td>{{ $post['comments'] }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ url('home/edit', $post['id']) }}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" id="deleteBtn" data-deleteid="{{ $post['id'] }}" data-href="{{ action('AddRecordController@destroy', $post['id']) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: Okay. Thank You. i will check on this one

Comment: Ive tried your code. This is what i get. 1/1) TokenMismatchException

Comment: Then you need to add the CSRF token.

Comment: Thank You for your help. i already solve it. :-)) i added CSRF token to the data